How to detect which submit button is used in a Livewire form?
This is a simplified version of a form I have in a Livewire component:
<form wire:submit="submitLivewireForm(globalPageType)">

    <input 
        id="product-name"
        name="product-name"
        type="text"
        wire:model="productName">

    <!-- Some more single line and multiline form
         elements with two-way binding -->

    <button id="action-generate-titles">
        Generate titles
    </button>

</form>

This works fine. The button submits the form, and the wire:submit stops the standard round-trip submission, and instead calls the PHP function on the remote server with the supplied global JS var as a parameter.
I now want several buttons, for different user actions. I tried adding a named button:
<input type="submit"
    name="action"
    value="Foo" />

I had hoped that I could access the name in the component, via Illuminate\Http\Request:
public function submitLivewireForm(Request $request, ?string $pageType): void
{
    // ...
}

But this does not seem to be available. I guess I could try adding a wire:model field, but this is merely UX architecture, so treating it as model data feels inappropriate.
Furthermore, if I remove the wire:submit from the form, and add a wire:click to the button, the form still does a round-trip submission, losing all the data.
What is the normal Livewire way to solve this problem?

I have found two ways to solve this. The first is by adding a click handler to a button, but leaving the form submit handler in place:
<input type="submit"
    name="action"
    wire:click="generatePageElements(globalPageType)"
    value="Submit button" />

Now that works, though I notice that the click handler and the form submit handler are both called, so I would either have to make the submit handler a no-op call on the server, or use JS to stop the form from submitting. The latter can simply be done like so (though I do not know how much inline JS is frowned upon these days):
<form onsubmit="return false;">

An even nicer way is just to use a link with a Livewire click handler, and then use the CSS framework (Bootstrap, Tailwind, etc) to dress it up as a button.
<a href="#"
    class=" ... "
    wire:click="generatePageElements(globalPageType)">Linky</a>

This just does one call, which is what I want.
Now I was surprised that either of these worked; they both seem to gather the form field element values, despite not using a form-level operation.
I remain open to more idiomatic ways of doing this in Livewire; I am trying to build a product, having not had the time to go through all the Laracasts material!
